# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columnidisnotunique(code19) android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: android, database, sqlite

first time when inserting the row it works without any issues. But the after installing the app in same device(installing from eclipse without uninstall the app from device) and trying to insert new row it throws exception

```
10-1216: 36: 38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429): Causedby:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columnidisnotunique(code19)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1565)
10-12 16:36:38.405: E/AndroidRuntime(32429):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
```

Create Table:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_DATA + "("
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_JSON_DATA + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Insert:

```
    public void addJsonData(JSONDataStore dataStore) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, dataStore.getKey());
    values.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, dataStore.getTimeStamp());
    values.put(KEY_JSON_DATA, dataStore.getJsonData());

    db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA, null, values);
}
```

Upgrade:

```
    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_DATA);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

Exception when inserting:

```
    db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to create two rows with the same value for column `ID` which is defined as `PRIMARY KEY`. In order to let sqlite create auto-increment ID values for you, just remove this line.-

```
values.put(KEY_ID, dataStore.getKey());
```

and declare the column as `INTEGER`.

Comment: But in my case primary key should be string only. I want to store the json file name as key, timestamp (json downloaded time) value and json string as another value for caching purpose I am storing timestamp. how to do this???

Comment: Are the json names unique? You should make sure to search for a row with a given name before inserting, if one exists, update instead of inserting.